# How can add two different size for two different fonts

Tags: html, css

How can add two different sizes for two different fonts?

This is my body CSS code:

```
body {
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: Roboto, Droid Arabic Kufi;
}
```

Roboto for English words and Droid Arabic Kufi for Arabic words, How can make if the word is English (Roboto) so the size be 13px but if it's Arabic (Droid Arabic Kufi) change the size to 12px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create both an english & arabic class including each `font-family` and `font-size`:

```
.english {
    direction: ltr;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.arabic {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Then assign it to the html element depending on which language is it:

```
<span class="english">english text 13px font size</span>
<span class="arabic">arabic text 12px font size</span>
```

Full snippet example (used Droid Sans as demo instead of Droid Arabic Kufi):

```css
.english {
  direction: ltr;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.arabic {
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<span class="english">english text 13px font size</span><br>
<span class="arabic">arabic text 12px font size</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to assign the fonts separately as the font for separately selected elements. I'd suggest using classes, one class for the English and one class for the Arabic words. Suppose you have a class `.english` and a class `.arabic` accordingly. Then you could have styles as follows:

```
.english {
  direction: ltr;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.arabic {
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: Droid Arabic Kufi;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

There is not a way to do this without using classes or some other way to uniquely identify elements that contain one language or the other.